# error: package RecyclerView does not exist

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, macos-catalina

While trying to build my repo I am running into following error:

`MyAdapter.java:XY: error: package RecyclerView does not exist`
   `static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

I am building with:

- Gradle 6.7
- on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Android target SDK 30
- AndroidStudio 4.1.1

Gradle is configured for AndroidX: 
`android.useAndroidX=true` 
`android.enableJetifier=true`

I can see in project navigation of AndroidStudio that the dependency was downloaded
and I can navigate the editor inside the class `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. 
Also important to mention that my repo can be build **w/o any issues on a Windows machine**.
Repo contains several modules which have also classes that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` but only this module **fails to build on MacOS**.
It seems that Gradle have different build process order in comparison to Gradle on Windows.

What I have tried:

- rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
- ./gradlew cleanBuildCaches
- re-installation of Android SDK
- re-installation of Android Studio
- excluded transitive dependency `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview` in libs by adding `exclude group: 'androidx.recyclerview', module: 'recyclerview'`

Does anybody had a similar issue or can give any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: had you try this implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"

Comment: @Amitpandey yes, this statement is available in gradle build config

Comment: Have you tried: `./gradlew clean` (not buildCaches) too? (and Android Studio invalidate -> restart) (I know you have reinstalled it, just indulge me here) :)

Comment: What happens if you do file -> new android project, and add a Recycler View, does that work? (simple test, grab one of the default templates for Empty activity or similar).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I have tried `./gradlew clean` and result was not successful. Also, tried with a new project (basic activity) where I added `androidx.recyclerview` as dependency and some other dependencies to have as much as possible the same dependency tree, the build was successful there. it seems that the issue has relation to submodules or build order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleagues using MacOS fixed this by adding an additional static import

```
import static androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder;
```

and changing

```
static class PageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

to

```
static class PageViewHolder extends ViewHolder
```

Works fine now on MacOS and Windows.

Comment: thanks, it works. This is a much more minimally invasive solution compared to my temp. solution where I placed my nested class `MyViewHolder ` into a separate class. I tried also to replace the remote cache with locally build cache artifacts (== macOs builds), but w/o any success. Do you know the reason why this happen or do you have any further information/thoughts to this strange issue?